# Jquery UI Datepicker disabling wrong days

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have run in to issue that days that have to be disabled are shifted to the next day.
The idea is that day that does not exist in our `booking` object or have a value less than 1 should be disabled on calendar.

here is simplified version of my script and demonstration on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhbLG/3/):

```
var bookings = {
    "2012-09-01": 24,
    "2012-09-03": 31,
    "2012-09-05": 27,
    "2012-09-06": 9, 
    "2012-09-07": 18, 
    "2012-09-08": 0, 
    "2012-09-10": 20, 
    "2012-09-12": 19, 
    "2012-09-13": 0, 
    "2012-09-14": 9, 
    "2012-09-15": 24, 
    "2012-09-17": 19, 
    "2012-09-19": 28, 
    "2012-09-20": 15, 
    "2012-09-21": 12, 
    "2012-09-22": 25, 
    "2012-09-24": 19, 
    "2012-09-26": 0, 
    "2012-09-27": 0, 
    "2012-09-28": 0, 
    "2012-09-29": 0
};

function MyEvent(date)
{
    bookings = bookings || {};
    this.date = date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    this.display = (typeof bookings[this.date] == 'number' && bookings[this.date] > 0);
    return this;
}

MyEvent.prototype.toArray = function () { 
    return [this.display, null, null]; 
};

$(function ()
{
    $('#eventCalendar').datepicker({
            dateFormat:    "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay:      1,
            defaultDate:   "2012-09-24",
            beforeShowDay: function (date)
            {
                return new MyEvent(date).toArray();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Can some one suggest me what am I doing wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little struggle, but is not a bug. 
There is a problem using:

```
date.toISOString()
```

the operation can return a different date (for example next day) from the original date passed from the plug in, because the function ignores timezone offsets

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

so your condition will not work well.

Here is a working fiddle the is not using that function: http://jsfiddle.net/nBejK/2/